# Extracting interested part of a string between '\' using regex

Tags: python, regex

I have the string `'[)>\x1E12\x1DMFR P0540\x1DPNR XY30357\x1DSER PPQRW599999901\x1E\x04'` and would like to use regex to extract data from the string of particular interest as listed below:

1. MFR P0540
2. PNR XY30357
3. SER PPQRW599999901

Comment: `\\x1D([^\\]+)` then access result from first group maybe?

Comment: @Aaron This results in None. My code in python is `re.search(r"\\x1D([^\\]+MFR)",m)` , where m is the string mentioned in the question

Comment: try without the first backslash maybe, I'm not sure whether your string contains the characters "\x1D" or the single character that escape sequence represents. `\x1D` isn't in the ASCII range if I'm not mistaken so that might require setting an UTF-8 flag for your regex

Comment: The pattern @Aaron shared works. Just make sure both `m` variable and pattern are a raw string too.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: You didn't write right away that it's Python, but I leave it to someone maybe useful.

Use GAWK if possible:

```
echo '[)>\x1E12\x1DMFR P0540\x1DPNR XY30357\x1DSER PPQRW599999901\x1E\x04' |gawk -v RS="x1D" '/[A-Z]{3} /{split($0,s,"\\"); print s[1]}'
```

result:

```
MFR P0540
PNR XY30357
SER PPQRW599999901
```